Advice on weather proofing my NYC coop window
Just moved into a new apartment and it's clear the window sill on the outside is not in great. It looks like there's some wood covered with a weatherstrip of sorts. Now I know this is technically the coops responsibility to manage, but I'd like to manage some of this myself and make sure it's done right.
I don't have any pictures underneath the weatherstrip, but here's what the window looks like. This one is doing better than the others, but sharing as a reference on what I'm talking about: https://imgur.com/a/uS1NtNX https://imgur.com/a/6pRV100
The ones in question had rotting wood and the weatherstrips were also not doing well. Any advice on what I should do to best waterproof these windows? And what I should purchase if I'm DIY this myself?

Before doing any work, you do want to get the coop's permission, in writing.  It is their building, so they do have a say about what you can do.

I think what you are calling a weatherstrip is the sill plate of the window.  Your pic doesn't show any issue.   It's impossible to help if we don't have a clear understanding of what is wrong.

Are you renting, or are you a member of the co-op?

I am a member of the coop, and very aware of needing the board's permission. I'm just trying to sort out what is going on as I'm not too familiar.

@RMDman - here are some additional pics I have of what's underneath: https://imgur.com/a/6pRV100. There used to be a wood block in that gap, which a previous contractor seemed to have removed. Thanks for the correction. I also thought it was the sill plate, but might've gotten confused after googling.

It looks like there was a wood trim sill piece that's rotted away.

I see no wood in either of your pics. I believe what you may have seen was an old wood remnant that was left when new windows were fitted into the building.
There is nothing that is readily identified as wood. However what it there is a hole. This hole should be filled. In general the areas look to only be needing a cleaning and further inspection.
With the Co-ops approval the windows should be cleaned of all debris. The large wad of caulking on the right in one pic, ( where the hole is) can be cut away to inspect the seal between the window frame and the side of the building. ( which looks like concrete)  After cutting away the extra caulking, there may not be anything else needed, or a conservative amount of polyurethane caulking applied, depending on what is found.
This is base on the pics you have provided. If there is evidence otherwise, please post clear pics of the issues with the areas of concern noted. Otherwise this is minor and nothing in need of immediate or concerted action.
